# User-Specific CSS

Tags: feature-request, design, preferences

It would be nice if users could add their own styles to the CSS-Rules on SO. This is nothing more than a textarea in the user preferences that takes precedence over the default styles.

Users could create themes that are easier for them to use, and share with others. Sure, I could use my own local browser to override the styles, but that won't benefit me working on the other two machines that I visit regularly from.

Comment: See also: [How to change all fonts on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300905/309993)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can already do custom stylesheets for websites with your web browser and some add on developer tools (or some are like that right out of the box). Having SO implement it on it's own seems to be a big waste.

**Edit**: [See this answer for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back/417#417)

Comment: That seems to be the standard response to most of the feature-requests here so far. Sorry, venting slightly. Just about anything can be done some other way - I could use Yahoo Pipes for this, greasemonkey for that, etc. Are we not encouraging the growth of SO to allow the community ease, or are we expecting everybody to hack their own solutions up on their own?

Comment: Jonathan Sampson: What you are asking is for SO to allow for users to hack their own solutions up on their own. I don't see how it is any different typing in your styles in a text area on SO instead of using a tool that is already out there (and would allow you to do more customization than just SO).

Comment: @Jonathan: custom stylesheets is a really really expensive thing for a site to provide for very little real benefit, especially over the available solutions

Comment: TheTXI, should I have to do that for every computer I work from too?

Comment: Jonathan Sampson: When we work from multiple computers we always have to spend time loading our favorite bookmarks, our favorite extensions, etc. I do not see how a one time stylesheet setup for your favorite sites should really be that much different if it matters that much to you. Like annakata said, providing that type of customization has such a large time/expense to benefit ratio that it really makes no sense to implement, especially when tools are already out there to handle this. Before long you'll have people wanting every site to cater to their own style whims.

Comment: I tend to recommend pipes greasemonkey, etc for things I really don't expect Jeff and Crew to do.  This is one of them.  97% of people will never use it, and the few who will could accomplish the same thing with a client workaround.

Comment: "Before long you'll have people wanting every site to cater to their own style whims." And what would be wrong with that? Seems rather brilliant to me. People love branding things - I would love to use my own custom colors/images on SO without having to sync up styles between computers if I make changes. Oh well. Thanks for the comments anyway.

Comment: What would be wrong with that? Well...probably the fact that it would only be utilized by tiny percentage of those actually visiting the site, making the development of that type of feature usually pretty worthless.

Comment: Wow. Sampson lives in an awesome dreamworld. I thought TheTXI with all his pony fantasies was way 'out there', but Sampson is taking that ball and running with it.

Comment: @Rich B - Sorry to see that people will be ridiculed for attempting to contribute.

Comment: *sigh* this again? here?

Comment: @Annakata, what do you mean by "this again?"

Comment: @Sampson: You are not contributing. You are asking the dev team to take time away from important things to implement a feature on the website that can already be (very adequately) handled client side. That is the opposite of contributing.

Comment: @Rich, Submitting feature-requests IS contributing. Opening up styling to the community would result in MORE contributions from Designer/Developers like myself who would create themes out of interest in the site.

Comment: @Sampson: *sigh* What do you not understand? The feature already exists. There is /no/ reason to do it server side. That is why it keeps getting declined. You /have/ the tools. /Use/ them.

Comment: Styling is already open to the community, again, through the tools that are already out there. There is nothing truly holding you back from creating themes out of interest in the site, other than your reluctance to use tools that are already in high use.

Comment: This is pointless.

Comment: @TheTXI: And now those people even have a place (metaSO) to post their themes... What more could they (realistically) want?

Comment: @Sampson: I agree. Server side custom stylesheets are pointless. That is why it keeps getting declined.

Comment: @Rich, are you so immature that you must twist my words in order to establish ground for yourself? "This is pointless" clearly isn't referring to themes (as I've been defending them). Ground around and around with you is pointless. Themes are NOT pointless. You apparently haven't met anybody with poor eye-sight, or somebody involved in marketing. Shoot, by your logic firefox's ability to create addons is pointless it would seem. Kinda odd that you're suggesting I use addons because addons are pointless.

Comment: @Sampson: That is a whole heap of logic fail.

Comment: @RichB, what on Earth are you talking about? How is it illogical to suggest/defend themes? What I fail to understand is your seemingly arbitrary sense of disconnection when it comes to discussing this item.

Comment: @Sampson: Once again, you are so far off the logical trail, I cannot argue. Everything has been explained to you thoroughly. If you don't get it, I cannot help you.

Comment: @Rich, I'm confused as to how exactly you're using the term "logical." Would you care to explain how it applies? Are you suggesting that if a person isn't persuaded by your arguments, they must be illogical? Affirming the consequent, much?

Comment: @Jonathon: I know you really want to keep your trolling going, but I think it is best you let it die.

Comment: @Rich Asking you to explain yourself for the benefit of my understanding is equivalent to trolling now?

Comment: The above 20 or so comments are what I meant by "this again?". There's a sad predictability to a conversation when Rich tilts his lance at it. Just walk away.

Comment: @Sampson: Yes. You are purposely mangling the argument to try and get a large, negative reaction. That is trolling.

Comment: @Rich Mangling the argument? Quote me, please. Your first comment here insulted both TheTXI and myself. Claiming my suggestion is tantamount to "pony fantasies" and being "way out there." If you've nothing better to say, then please keep your silence. Some of us are here for the discussion.

Comment: @Sampson: Exhibit A: "Themes are NOT pointless. You apparently haven't met anybody with poor eye-sight, or somebody involved in marketing."

Comment: @Sampson: Exhibit B: "Shoot, by your logic firefox's ability to create addons is pointless it would seem. Kinda odd that you're suggesting I use addons because addons are pointless. "

Comment: @Rich [Exhibit A] - I don't get what your charge is. If you suggest that themes are pointless, then I'm safe in assuming you have never met anybody with poor eye-sight, or you've never been involved in marketing. Where's the insult there?

Comment: @Rich [Exhibit B] - Again, what is the problem? You are arguing that I use firefox addons because it's a waste to addon to SO.

Comment: @Sampson: See, there is where you fail. Where did I (or anyone else) say 'themes are pointless'?

Comment: @Rich, I don't really take your offensive behavior personal after reading the comments you leave for others on their questions - seems insulting people is not foreign to your involvement here. Either way, best wishes to you.

Comment: @Sampson: Exhibit C: "Where's the insult there?"

Comment: @Sampson: If you find someone not agreeing with you offensive, or you find someone calling your broken logic out and refusing to argue with your broken logic offensive, then I suppose you probably should give up.

Comment: @Rich "Server side custom stylesheets are pointless." As a synonym for themes - since that IS what we're talking about.

Comment: @Rich, Care to actually plot out the logical inconsistency in my position/defense of themes? You keep using that word "logic" as if it's some silver-bullet to winning a discussion - explain what it is you are referring to.

Comment: @Sampson: Right. And my argument is that these should be implemented client side with existing tools. So I am not saying themes are pointless, only that your implementation of them is. Reading comprehension and context are important for effective communication.

Comment: @Rich, I don't find it offensive that somebody disagree with me. I find it offensive the way you chose to disagree with me, and with others on SO.

Comment: @Rich, again, do you think users should have to implement local themes for every machine they work on, and be quick to sync personally whenever any changes are made? Seems to me server-side themes solve that problem pretty easily.

Comment: @Sampson: It seems to me that when a tool readily exists, it is kind of pointless to think that the devs on a site would reimplement it on their site. Especially when it is something as arbitrary as aesthetics. Copying a style sheet among a few computers you happen to use seems way more logical than the devs taking on this kind of initiative and all the problems that will come with it.

Comment: @Rich I think you're confusing "logical" with "practical." I see what you mean though. But from experience, when Channel9 implemented this very feature it was widely accepted by the community, and even drove more community-involvement towards contributing to the layout/functionality of the site. Many, including myself, contributed to what others could easily experience without being limited to browsers/addons/etc. You're suggesting users should download firefox, download addons, etc. I'm suggesting a simple field to the user-table, and nothing more.

Comment: @Sampson: If you truly think this could be implemented with only a field being added to the user table, then I see why you think this is such a great idea. And I realize why you will never see why the rest of us think it is a bad idea.

Comment: @Rich, Yes. I do think it's a simple addition. Create a locale for the data in the database. Map a textarea from the prefs tab, filter out unwanted style-overriding when accepting text for storage. What am I missing? The styles are only shown to those who wish to see them.

Comment: @Samson - forget arguing with him.  I suspect his issue(s) is listed somewhere in the DSM-IV and it is best to walk away.

Answer (score 3):

If you have firefox (and being here suggests you should) then you have access to [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) and [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) both of which can accomplish what you want.

I use the latter for highlighting interesting things on SO and the former for not making me feel like I'm dying slowly when I'm here.

Comment: Seriously, downvote?

Comment: I upvoted.    `

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete fix but you could just use the custom stylesheets if your browser supports them. Wouldn't work on non-compatible browsers and be a pain if you change computers a lot (as a lot of programmers do)