# Why is this site so drab?

Tags: discussion

**Duplicate Post**:

[Here's a Meta UserVoice Question: Can You Bring The Color Back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back)

---

The colors (or lack there of) are KILLING MY EYES. Is it just me or is it really awful?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back

Comment: Please look at other questions before you post.

Comment: Need 3K rep...Can I transfer some from SO.

Comment: How long until we stop getting duplicates of this on meta?  I say it'll never stop.

Comment: Until the search improves or the color changes?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad so sad.   **It is just you (Answer to your 'question').**  Try to phrase it as a real question like [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back) did.  This is still a Q and A site.

Comment: It actually isn't just him. There was a pretty popular thread (see my answer) which already discussed this and there are quite a few unhappy folks (although it has improved some with the way links are handled now)

Comment: I know.  **I just don't like people who whine.**  I also linked to that question.  I agree that the colors suck btw.

Comment: jinguy: You sound like you're whining :P

Comment: I also **hate** hypocrites!!!!

Comment: and whiners!!!!  (this is not looking good for me)

Answer (score 0):

[Can you bring the color back to meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/heres-a-meta-uservoice-question-can-you-bring-the-color-back)