# Questions tagged with interesting tags are too orange on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

I don't like the orange color of the questions with tags which are in my 'Interesting tags' list.

They just distract me too much. Do other people also think they are too orange? Should they be more yellow/lighter? Or gray. Or have a shadow? Just instead of the annoying orange colour. On meta it's light gray which I think is better.

[image]

Comment: You are correct, SOFU needs more lens flare. And gradients.

Answer (score 4):

The higlighting is just fine for me. You might want to Greasemonkey it if it does not suit you.

Answer (score 3):

It's OK, because you see immediately, what questions are in your "Interesting tags".

Gray is color of meta (sad color)

Comment: see my answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/119#119

Answer (score 3):

You are never going to come up with a color scheme that works for 100% of the userbase, and so far the current color scheme on SO has worked well enough for the vast majority of users. The color is supposed to make it stand out, and it does its job well. If you have issues with the scheme, you can always get something like GreaseMonkey or some other personal stylesheet editor and change it up to something that better suits you.

Comment: Amen: As a colorblind dude, I fully support the color choice on SO.

Answer (score 2):

With thousands of people, you will *never* come up with a color scheme that everyone agrees on - least of all with a community of designers (and wannabe designers).

I, for one, like it. But even if I didn't, does it really matter? Meta is littered with posts about how Meta is too grey, SU is too blue, etc. Unless its an actual degradation of the user experience (text is unreadable or is too washed out to read properly) follow the old song and let it be.