# Should frequently used tags (i.e. used to tag about half of all questions) be added to Frequented Tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, stack-exchange

Before I added [a dummy tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dummy-tag-to-hide-frequented-tags) to Ignored Tags on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/, I could (or rather *was forced to*) see the Frequented Tags section. It contained a single tag - 'sharepoint-2010'. Since this is a site about SharePoint, **almost all the questions were highlighted** and that contradicts the idea of highlighting **selected, most valuable/interesting** questions.

In my opinion it is a bug. Tags with such a broad scope should not be added to Frequented Tags.

[image: too much highlighting]

Comment: Does it not indicate a specific version?

Comment: @systempuntoout It does, but it is the latest version of SharePoint, currently 373 questions out of 777 are tagged with 'sharepoint-2010'. Go to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ and see how the main page looks.

Comment: These things are bound to happen with a site that's *entirely devoted to a single technology*. This wasn't a problem when the questions were posted on Stack Overflow. But it's not clear what you're asking here. Do you want to remove the tag `sharepoint-2010`?

Comment: @Cody Gray Yes, that's why I am suggesting that algorithm generating the Frequented Tags list needs a change.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. It's not the algorithm's fault that the majority of questions have that tag. What do you propose to change the algorithm to instead? How does it know which of your frequented tags to ignore and which of them to actually count? You could just tell it yourself, of course...

Comment: @Cody Gray Take a look at the screenshot - is **highlighting most of the questions** good or bad? Does it help to achieve anything?

Comment: Nearly *all* of the questions on my Stack Overflow homepage are highlighted. Makes sense, it means the algorithm is correctly finding questions that I would be interested in or would probably be able to answer. But you're still missing the point. You're making a "feature-request", but not spelling out what you want that "feature" to be. "Don't highlight the questions I don't want to be highlighted" is not an algorithm.

Comment: Also see: [Questions tagged with interesting tags are too orange on StackOverflow.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/questions-tagged-with-interesting-tags-are-too-orange-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: @cody that's not really the same since the SO homepage does something radically different than every other site. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Answer (score 6):

Having a tag that covers *more than half of the questions* seems disproportionate. Is this tag really relevant? Are all the questions tagged `sharepoint-2010` really specific to that version?

Let's look at the top tags on a few sites:

- [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/): 794 questions, 493 (62%) [`sharepoint-2010`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/sharepoint-2010), 140 `sharepoint-2007`, 56 [`development`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/development).
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/): 1349 questions, 618 (46%) [`drupal-6`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/drupal-6), 542 [`drupal-6`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/drupal-6), 150 [`views`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/views).
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/): 6290 questions, biggest tag 673 (11%) [`plugins`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/plugins), biggest version tag 313 [`wordpress-3`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/wordpress-3).
- [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/): 14194 questions, 1893 [`10.10`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/10.10), 1555 (11%) [`11.04`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/11.04), 915 [`10.04`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/10.04), 902 [`unity](https://askubuntu.com/tags/unity).
- [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/): 6519 questions, 930 (14%) [`meaning`](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/meaning).
- [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/): 4040 questions, 840 (21%) [`linux`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/linux).

I haven't looked at the content of Drupal and SharePoint, but from these figures I suspect that WordPress and Ubuntu are doing this right and Drupal and SharePoint are doing it wrong.  I included English in this list because I think they've done a good job of getting useful tags with a difficult subject matter. I included Unix partly because I know it well, and partly to show that even though something like 95% of the questions are from people running Linux¹, most of these questions don't have the `linux` tag because it's not relevant to the question.

Enforcing that a version or variant tag is only used when it matters takes some work (I know I retag a lot on Unix), but it's worthwhile to be able to search version-specific questions if you find you have a version-specific issue (it worked under 2007, no longer does under 2010, so I want to search 2010-specific answers only), or to ignore versions you don't care about.

Concluding with something that directly addresses your question: on Unix, where I have no favorite tags and view almost every question, no question is highlighted.

¹  <sub>That was an off-the-cuff estimate, but the questions tagged with unix variants other than Linux do seem to add up to around 5%.</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for bringing this to my attention; see http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful and http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as others have said, this implies a deep problem with the tagging scheme on your site.

We generally *strongly discourage* version tags unless the question you are asking is irrevocably and perfectly linked to a specific version of software, and *cannot possibly ever be relevant to any other version of the software for the rest of recorded human history*.

So unless sharepoint 2010 is completely and radically different than sharepoint 2007 -- I'm talking about a change so radical that it went from Windows to Linux -- it is unlikely you need this many questions tagged sharepoint 2010.

edit: elaborated and proposed policy of **version tags considered harmful** at

- [Version tags considered harmful](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful) (sharepoint)
- [Version tags considered harmful](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/version-tags-considered-harmful) (drupal)