# Badge for accepted answers with a certain number of downvotes

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

There should be bronze, silver and gold badges awarded to accepted answers with a certain number of downvotes.

Take a look at [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/119#119), an accepted answer with a whopping of -42 downvotes! It's not easy to get your answer downvoted 30++ times, and it is not easy to get your answer accepted. Don't you think to get both is an accomplishment?

Comment: Atwood would get those badges multiple times on Meta before any other user even pockets one.

Comment: I love this idea. Anyone who dislikes the badge proposal for scoring the accepted answer with downvotes has never posted an answer on a question tagged for C++. There are some real competitive folks on that tag that love to downvote over very nitpicky reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

I don't see why we would like to reward a bad answer (judged so by the community) which is taken as accepted (depending only on the asker's judgment).

The opposite makes sense, and this is why it is rewarded ([Populist badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/37/populist)).

Badges exist to "encourage" a good behavior, remember that.

Answer (score 1):

As Gnoupi said, we don't want to reward bad answers.

If you were proposing new Badges for SO/SF/SU, your example shouldn't have been taken from Meta, where downvoting means something different.

Jeff's answer wasn't *technically* bad, it was just unpopular.