# [Meta] Please! Change the site color

Tags: discussion, meta, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you bring the color back to meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta)

Please change this site's color scheme. It is hard on my eyes, therefore I have boycotted it until area51 claimed this as their meta site. Now I have to be here.

### PLEASE ADD SOME BLUE AND GREEN.

**Or at least a lot more red and blue.**

Answer (score 1):

I always thought it was kind of clever, like all the "real" sites are colorful while this behind-the-scenes site is monochrome. But it's possible I read way too much into it and they just couldn't come up with another clever color scheme when they rolled out meta

Comment: if my choices are "because we are awesome" and "because we couldn't think of anything else", I choose the former!