# Accepted answer color differs on meta

Tags: support, accepted-answer, meta, design

First: I am very aware of this question: [Can you bring the color back to meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta)

But I am not asking to change the color theme, but I am asking to make the yellow color of the accepted answer on meta the same on every page.

What I mean: When you go to the start page of meta, the answered questions are extremely hard to identify. The used yellow color code there is `#FBFABD`

When you search, the color on the search result page for the accepted answers is `#E1E818`. Its not a very big difference, but its really better to see. At least for me.

What I don't understand is, why the use of different color at all. The yellow number is good to see on the search result page, but the "x answers" is again the same color like on the main page. Shouldn't that be somehow consistent?