# Color of questions with accepted answers on user profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, meta, design

Related to these questions:
[Accepted answer color differs on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79040/167443)
[MSO color coding - accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100355/167443)

When viewing the **Meta user profile**, the difference between questions with accepted answers and questions without is pretty subtle. At first glance, I couldn't tell the difference at all. Can the contrast between the styles be increased a bit to make it easier to see?

[image]

This screenshot doesn't look too bad, but when looking at a list going down a whole page, it gets a bit difficult to pick one out at a glance. (I'm guessing even more so for some of the color-challenged users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it was solved when MSO became MSE :)

> [image]

Its very clear that first and last questions were accepted.

Comment: Yes. Looks like this is fixed on both MSO and MSE.