# New Stack Overflow Mobile Site?

Tags: support, mobile-web

A few days ago my iPhone started rendering Stack Overflow a bit differently, using duller colors, trimmed-down buttons, etc.  (I am on StackOverflow.com - **NOT** the mobile site)

Is this some sort of opimization they've put in to reduce bandwidth going to mobile devices, or is something else going on?  I don't suppose there's a way to revert back?  Even AT&T can likely handle the few extra KB :)

I'm sorry if this has been answered already - I searched, but didn't find anything.

Comment: It was... *indirectly* answered in some other questions about the iPad (which was, temporarily, considered a mobile device due to Mobile Safari). There actually hasn't been a strict question about the mobile theme in general, so I'm actually quite happy you asked this one. ♪

Comment: Since when have SE Team ever give you options about the site? It's their way or no way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed [a new mobile theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689), which (I believe) detects the user agent to determine whether or not to show a minimized theme:

> We also offer a rudimentary "slimmed down, minimalistic" CSS theme when mobile devices are detected. It's pretty basic at the moment but does reduce the footprint substantially of the more styled Stack Exchange network sites.

The mobile theme uses 16 color greyscale images, so the site theme itself is greyscale to match that.

There's a [request for making it optional here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/view-standard-site-option-for-mobile-devices), so if you are interested please consider upvoting it.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the backup! ♪ I was actually just operating from a deleted question, so having something to actually link is nice.