# Sites don't have any theme in mobile Safari

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, iphone, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Stack Overflow Mobile Site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81370/new-stack-overflow-mobile-site)

I noticed that SO didn't look like SO on my iPhone a while ago, but when I visited some of the other sites today I noticed they *all* look the same.  It's as if they're all running some sort of bare theme.  The only way to tell the difference between them is the title, which is where the site logo should be.  Also, on question posts, the Facebook and Twitter icons are gone; `Share (Fb)` and `Share (Tw)` have taken their places.

I'll post the screenies I took later if I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Mobile devices use a simplified mobile theme that is identical across all sites. The theme remains in beta and IIRC, it has been said that it will be possible to choose between the mobile theme and the full theme in the future.

Comment: Not *all* mobile devices.  I still have yet to see the mobile theme on my Android tablet...

Comment: It's a bit of a pain that they all look the same.  Hopefully that option to switch will come soon.