# Switching back to mobile theme after switching to full site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

While playing around with the new mobile theme I saw a tiny little link at the bottom for the full site.

However, I very much like the mobile theme over the desktop version, and the desktop version doesn't seem to have a link to switch back.

Can we have a link for switching back? Please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After our next deploy there will be a "mobile" link in the footer, only shown if you're browsing the desktop site with a mobile user-agent.

Comment: This is now live, and I can confirm that it works as expected. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't find link on SE home page