# Suggested topics while typing a question causing display problem

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

I am having a little bit of a problem here. When I type my message, there is a list of suggested existing questions on the right side. When I scroll down, the field moves to the right of my screen, making it impossible to view. This happens on all Stack Exchange web sites.

I am using Firefox 8. Also, I am using a remote desktop which makes my screen very small (800x600). I am using remote desktop because I can't use Visual Studio on Ubuntu.  Anyway, this is how it looks:

[image]

This is the second problem [I have pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114636/174102) while browsing this network in small screen.

Comment: First of all, I pity you for using VS on 1024x768. Secondly, why are visiting the Internet from that remote place, and not local?

Comment: @Bobby: Put the problem still exists. I am using local screen for watching videos.

Comment: Sorry, I never meant to question the problem, I was only curious.

Comment: Your screenshot looks like it's original size, and it's 802 pixels wide. Where do you get the 1024 from?

Comment: @balpha♦: You are right. I will update my OP.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum screen width we support is 1024 pixels. Using anything narrower than that should work in most cases, but sometimes issues like this one can appear; if you're using smaller screens (or equivalent RDP windows), you'll have to live with that.

Comment: Plus, when I am on top of the page this block appears normal; only when I scroll down a little it makes the block go wild.

Comment: +1. This is 2011, not 2001. They shoudln't need to support 800x600 any more. 1024 is the absolute least people should use nowadays (unless you have to use some poor 15" CRT brick of a moniter, in which case it's time for a) a new screen or b) a new job.)

Comment: He could use the mobile version of the site, perhaps?

Comment: @Brock Adams: Is there one?

Comment: Ok, you don't support such screen resolution. How about having window split vertically and then rendering page? Is this still not supported?

Comment: Yes, there is a mobile version of the site.  Alas, SO has refused so far to provide an explicit URL-scheme for it!!!  To use it, [change your browser agent to report one of the officially hip-enough devices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81235).

Comment: @BrockAdams: Why would you need an "explicit URL-scheme" when *every single page* contains a "mobile" link?

Comment: @balpha, because I was going off what Jeff said in the blog announcement and that question answer, and I never noticed the mobile link?  (^_^)  It would still be nicer to be able to explicitly link to mobile versions of the pages.  It cuts clutter and can be oh so helpful when referencing SE for/to newbies.

Comment: @Balpha is 1024 still the current minimum? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251836/252153