# 1024 pixels wide: overlap between time of activity and site icon in network profile (activity tab) and other issues

Tags: bug, design, area-51, network-profile

Looks like site CSS's aren't fit for 1024 pixel-wide screens.

Link: https://stackexchange.com/users/1816341/deer-hunter?tab=activity

The image shows it all ("11m" overlaps the SEx.SE beta logo):
[image: Bug picture]

Extra info: Firefox 36.0.4, 1024x600 screen.

Link: https://area51.stackexchange.com

[image: Area 51 oddness]

Comment: [No repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X08MW.png), everything looks pretty pretty. What browser? Are you zooming?

Comment: Firefox 36.0.4. No zoom. No styling scripts. either.

Comment: No repro with same exact browser. Try to clear your cache, disable extensions etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I'm afraid it's because of unusual (1024x600) screen resolution.

Comment: I tried to repro in responsive mode but no luck...

Comment: No repro Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04, 1920 x 1080

Comment: To upvoters who see the same issue: please share your experience. "No repro" comments make me fear a PEBKAC case this side of the monitor :P

Comment: @Deer afraid this resolution is not supported, same way IE6 is not supported. Let me see if it's official. Hmm.... three years ago [1024 was the minimum supported screen width](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114826/152859) so it might have changed over time. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard - would be grateful for an authoritative response on minimum requirements nowadays.

Comment: @DeerHunter sure, me too. :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with screen resolution, just with the very wide characters in your browser's default font.