# Make links in downvoted posts be grey, just like the text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, down-votes, design

Downvoted posts are nicely rendered some sort of greyish. However, links are not. That makes links in such posts stand out even more.

If there is some wish list for minor CSS tweaks: maybe make the links grey too?

[image: URLs in spam post standing out]

Comment: Err, if I thought the `[low-priority]` tag would have a meaning for feature requests, I would have added it. How can this be 13 upvotes already...? Go [vote for more privacy instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink)! ;-)

Comment: The reason that the text is gray is because that post makes you eligible for the Peer Pressure badge if you delete it. So it doesn't gray until it hits -3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now make the entire answer semi-transparent, instead of just changing the font color.  This should make everything appear lighter / grayed out.

Comment: [Example post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/119#119)

Comment: Ah, David, did you see @lunboks example? [That](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/119#119) renders with kind of black links for me. ([Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FTdm5.png), [Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zw4os.png) on Mac OS X.)