# Do not grey-out comments on greyed-out Answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, down-votes, visibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It is hard to read (comments at) a downvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117344/it-is-hard-to-read-comments-at-a-downvoted-answer)

If an Answer ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104398/)) is heavily downvoted, it gets greyed-out, which is fine. The problem is that the punishment is also handed out to the comments, which really should stand out as they tend to explain the low rating of the Answer.

Comment: duplicate: [It is hard to read (comments at) a downvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117344/165773)

Answer (score 6):

I find it readable enough. If I want to know why the answer should be ignored I can find out, otherwise it is easy to ignore the whole post including associated comments.

I don't want the comments to break up the page by being *overly* visible, standing out from the answer. Sometimes the comments are nothing but a "but I am RIGHT"/"no you are WRONG" fest anyway.