# Flag dialogs for grayed-out posts are also grayed-out

Tags: bug, design, flag-dialog

When flagging an answer that is grayed-out because it has a score of -3 or lower, the flag dialog is also grayed-out. If you drag it over a non-grayed-out answer, it appears semi-transparent. The same is true when you flag a comment on a grayed-out answer.

[image: semi-transparent grayed-out flag dialog]

This looks like a regression of [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40111/234299), perhaps due to [this recent bugfix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288436/176646).

Comment: (and also "share" popup)

Comment: And also edit :) Maybe this was by-design?

Comment: Came here to report the same issue.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed for posts. Not yet for comments though.

Comment: @epimorphic Looks like comments are like that by design. See [Jin's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers#comment170455_288963) about the [fix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288963/176646) that was deployed this morning: "The fix was, instead of setting .5 opacity on .downvoted-answers div, I limited the opacity to its .post-text, .post-signature, .votecell, .comments divs only. So this way it doesn't affect the popup div."

Comment: It's about as by-design as the problem with posts, no? Both are due to (1) CSS selectors not being as fine as is necessary and (2) flag dialogs residing within semi-transparent elements.

Comment: @epimorphic It's by design because the dev who just fixed the problem with the dialogs this morning *specifically and intentionally left it that way for comments.* Also note that [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117344/it-is-hard-to-read-comments-at-a-downvoted-answer) [previous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156817/do-not-grey-out-comments-on-greyed-out-answers) feature requests to make comments easier to read on grayed-out posts were declined.

Comment: @epimorphic I completely misunderstood you. I thought you were talking about *comments*, not the *flag dialog* for comments. You're right, this is still broken for the comment flag dialog. Good catch.

Comment: That's what I meant. Apologies for the vague wording.

Comment: @epimorphic I don't know what I was thinking...considering that the screenshot in my question is of the comment flag dialog, I should have known right away what you were talking about.

Answer (score 7):

In its current state it is very hard to use. In addition to the screenshot I gave in a comment earlier, I ran into this just now (Chrome on Ubuntu):

[image]

Earlier example was (Chrome on Windows):

[image]

Workaround is to move the flag dialog to somewhere that makes it visible.

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of the modal dialog `"#popup-flag-post"` being opened as a descendant of the answer, which in this case has class `".downvoted-answer"` giving that element and all of its descendant elements `opacity : 0.5`.

It does not seem necessary to nest the dialog in the answer because the position seems to be positioned relative to the page anyway with `position:absolute` and exact `top` and `left` values set.

The nesting comes as a result of the code inside of full.en.js, specifically where StackExchange.question seems to refer to this jQuery selector in order to use appendTo with it

```
var i = e.closest(".post-menu, .help-menu");
```

Which will essentially take the clicked element from the set, find the relevant container, and place the absolutely positioned dialog as a child in it. This could be changed by altering the append to be to the body of the page as opposed to the `.post-menu, .help-menu`.

<strike>However, Is this really a bug? To me it seems like it could also be [status-bydesign].</strike>

Comment: I'd say it was a bug. The dialog is very hard to use in it's current state.

Comment: The [first time this happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text) it was fixed and marked as status-complete, so I highly doubt it's by design.

Comment: Only by-design if it was designed to be [impossible to use](http://i.snag.gy/l7JTf.jpg).

Comment: In the older design, the fading out was applied to `.downvoted-answer .post-text`.  Specifically [because of this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110817/259867). So yeah, a regression due to "simplified" CSS.