# Flag dialog for faded offensive posts appears below answer editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editor, flag-dialog

*Similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251757/202832), but containing more bugginess.*

Take a look at this:

[image]

The post was grayed out because it received (presumably) 3 offensive flags. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29198446/1234256) was simply a random string of profanities.

Grayed out? Good. Grayed out flag dialog? Not good, but [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251757/202832). The editor has a higher `z-index` than the flag dialog. Definite original [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Please fix.

**Update:** In some situations, it can even appear *below other answers* making selecting a flag option impossible. The only workaround is to drag the box -- using the top right corner -- to whitespace on the right side. Then the post may be flagged.

Comment: A small query I made to make it easy for users to confirm the bug:  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291675/top-25-unsung-answers

Comment: But the editor tools don't have this! Interesting...

Comment: This bug *still* exists, is it ever going to be fixed?

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ 6-8 weeks, usually, for bugs that don't get immediate attention. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just flagged the question to request a moderator to make it featured, this way it's more likely that a developer sees it. If they don't make it featured, hopefully they'll have the sense to pass it onto the SE team directly.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ pointless, the moderators here **are** the developers. They see all bugs, but for their own reasons deemed this one as "we'll handle it at some point in the future", like 99% of the bugs. (can't and not blaming them, they do have more important things to do. Spam sticking for hours instead of minutes is not the end of the world :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not all moderators are developers, this is a serious issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ all moderators here on MSE are Stack Exchange employees, and anyway it doesn't matter - they do see and watch all bug reports, I saw them say this more than once. Flagging a bug report for extra attention is like yelling at someone's ear. (and likely will get declined)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, seeing as this has been reported a few times on both MSE and MSO, the bug's affecting many.

Comment: [should be fixed in next build](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288963/447356)

Comment: Still not fixed, not sure why [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @JasonC Fixed on the new design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stack Exchange employee Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin) posted [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288963/1234256) to the counterpart of [this bug on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288840/1234256):

> I have pushed a fix for this to dev. It will be on live after our next build. Thank you those who suggested solutions.

They also confirmed in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288840/flag-window-is-semi-transparent-for-downvoted-answers/288963?noredirect=1#comment170454_288963) this issue would be fixed network-wide.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me today when I was flagging a spam answer:

[image]

This bug's pretty annoying and it's been around for quite a while.

In my opinion it's a serious design flaw and should be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Yup, it cause many users to not flag spam, causing the spam to  stick much longer.