# Flag Window : Other Section TextField come out of boundry

Tags: bug, flags, design, google-chrome

I'd experienced a bug in Flag Window.

**Browser :** Google Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit)), Firefox (Version 36.0.4)

**OS :** Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

In flag window last option **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** containing a Text field to write details about flag. It goes out of Flag window.

*It occurs in normal browsing as well as in private browsing/incognito mode.*

> [image]

Comment: Second bug [already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251855/flag-dialog-for-faded-offensive-posts-appears-below-answer-editor), better remove it from here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard done. removed already reported bug.

Comment: Cheers, also add what browser/OS you're using and all is good. (can't repro with Chrome for example)

Comment: Also, are you on mobile device by any chance?

Comment: @Oded he just edited, it's Ubuntu - hope you have access to try and repro?

Comment: @Sha - not at my current location.

Comment: @SilentKiller any browser extensions you can remove? Can you try with a different browser?

Comment: @Sha - face the same with Firefox Ver-36.0.4.

Comment: So likely OS issue, rendering the built-in textbox in different way than Windows causing different width. Unless someone else with Ubuntu will come and say it's working fine, in which case it's more tricky.