# My answers don't get accepted - what can I do?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

On Arqade I am kinda well informed. After my registration on it, I answered several questions on the same topic, asked by the same person. Now these answers are about two weeks old and I know the asker is active (based on activity). What can I do to make him accept my answers?

I know that my answers are correct and I am the only answerer. Is there anything I could do? I even tried by a comment where I asked him why he doesn't accept, but got no reaction.

Comment: You can do nothing. And don't push users into accepting anything. They are free to accept whatever they like, whenever they see fit. In fact, there's no obligation to accept anything.

Comment: Okay, then ill wait more ^^ thx

Comment: @Ekonion: waiting is good, but also accept the fact that he might never re-visit that question and never accept any answer. That's perfectly fine and acceptable!

Comment: But doesnt it work demoralizing, if answeted questions are not accepted? I mean, maybe one of the users haves the luck and getting no amswer accepted. Dont you think, he would lose the *fun*?i mean if he thinks that noone takes care of his answers?

Comment: @Ekonion Overall users are playing the game just fine. They will accept and vote and do whatever the system allows them to do. But occasionally that doesn't happen. Just move on. Great answers will get much more reputation in terms of upvotes and your answer will still stand out.

Comment: Hmmmm.... alright then ^^

Comment: @Bart "You can do nothing" oh c'mon! There's plenty one can do. I for one shake my head in despair in cases like this - works like a charm

Comment: Keep it up and you'll get the Unsung Hero badge.

Comment: XD right, i forgot about that ^^ but i think it need a little more than 5 unaccepted in opposite of 11 accepted ^^

Comment: @Daniel Daranas And btw is the  unsung hero badge about accepted woth zero votes ^^

Comment: @Ekonion Oops, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: the community should have a go in this case as well. if the OP doesnt accept the answer within 2 weeks let the community vote up if the answer shall be accepted!

Comment: @mehow that's not the point. The community gets to upvote to show appreciation, the OP gets to mark acceptance to mark *a verified working solution for his unique problem*. The community cannot decide that for him, they can just vote their appreciation of quality and correctness, applicability is a different perspective.

Comment: @mehow: The idea of the community (or Community) accepting an answer when the asker doesn't has been floated here a number of times and has been declined with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Write better answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The Rule of Life

Don't expect from others that you will definitively get the reward.

**Some reason as per my opinion :**

- He/she will not accept until they didn't get proper output.
- Might be they are unable to understand your answer.
- They are not satisfied with answer.
- Might be they are waiting for better, efficient or short lesson.
- Might be he/she hasn't checked your answer yet.
- Don't know how to accept.
- It could be more...

At the end we can't compel the user to accept our answer. If they wish and they are okay with your answer, then they will accept it.

BTW It's my opinion.

Comment: Nice opinion friend

Comment: @chintan khetiya +ve thoughts i m giving +1 ..:)

Comment: Or they don't know that accepting answers is a thing.

Comment: Still, there should be a way to ask moderators to "accept" an answer for a person that asked a question and never bothers to accept. A bit like closed questions work, after 5 "mod accept", the answer could be accepted?

Answer (score 6):

> What can I do, to make him accept my answers?

Nothing. You don't need to do anything to make the OP accept your answer. Accepting the answer completely depends on the OP. It is his choice whether to accept or not. Accepting an answer means that it helped the OP to solve his problem. It doesn't mean the answer is good. Sometimes [wrong/bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598790/1369235) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120108/1369235) [are also accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6828780/1369235). So don't focus on acceptance. Just post good answers, the community will reward you surely by upvoting.

Comment: Ahhh, a point i didnt realize. Thx ^^

Comment: -29 on an accepted answer, that's really epic.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - Here is [the epic of epics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/187824) but not a bad answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with all the other posters here that it's just 'the way things go around here', I do think it harms the quality of the knowledge base that (judging by my own history) a majority of the questions do not get an accepted answer, even frequently despite the OP thanking in comments for the working solution ([notable example of this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701483/ie-6-7-8-not-loading-all-of-the-stylesheet/16701575#16701575)).

I think it **could** be a good idea, that if after a week a question does have upvoted answers, yet the OP has not accepted one yet, he gets a notification in his inbox asking him to verify whether there really wasn't one good enough for his problem there. He can then ignore it, or verify it and decide still not to accept, so still no force is applied, but it could be a good incentive to increase the value of the site as knowledge base.

Comment: I would say, after four weeks the most upvoted is auto accepted, this can be undone by flagging or starting a bounty

Comment: [The point of accepted answers is not to reward the most upvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181629/my-answers-dont-get-accepted-what-can-i-do/181686?noredirect=1#comment552452_181629). An answer might get a million upvotes but still not solve the OP's problem, then it **should not be accepted**, automatically or manually.

Comment: Hmmmm.. i see....