# Questions with 1 answer (not accepted) get ignored by people

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Normally if anyone asks a question and there are no answers it usually stays up the top of the page - if its a relatively new question. Many people get to see it and the possibility of getting a good answer is huge. However, some people post incomplete answers, or answers that do not solve the problem. In that case the question is pushed down the main SO page ( within the tags ) and people tend to ignore it assuming the question has already received an answer ( accepted or not ). So my concern is: what can I do ( besides placing a bounty ) to receive more answers/views on my question?

Comment: The question is pushed down by new questions being posted (or answered, depending on whether you're on the "newest" or "active" tab), regardless of whether it has answers or not. If it gets a new answer, it is bumped on the "active" tab.

Comment: Which page are you talking about? [interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting), [active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) or [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)?

Comment: Active Tab which is loaded by default

Comment: [Here is your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181629/my-answers-dont-get-accepted-what-can-i-do/181633#181633)

Comment: that is not even related to this topic. nice try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions that have got only 0 score answers are still highly visible in the [*Unanswered tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) and should get the attention you need. Alternatively you can flag (and eventually delete) incomplete or very low quality answers. Also remember that [*Community*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) (the SO bot) randomly pokes old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention.

Comment: I understand the mechanics. Maybe I wasnt clear enough with my original question. The problems arise when a question gets an answer - where the answer is incorrect, misleading, doesnt solve the problem etc. Even myself, and i think its a common behavior, when I look at the active tab questions and some already have an answer or two i tend to skip them and look for the ones that have not been answered yet. Therefore the OP is stack with a bad answer and it becomes much harder to get as much attention as he would if there was no answer

Comment: @mehow, as I said, in case of incomplete answers or very low quality ones you should flag them and get them deleted (as well as downvoting them) in order to go back at having 0 *real* answers.

Comment: yea i guess you are right. I wouldnt want people who originally tried to help to feel like im not appreciating their effort

Comment: voting down an answer doesn't mean "you suck". it means "this is not a helpful answer".