# How to bump a question with no useful answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, bump

My question: [Unable to change options for Twitter Bootstrap modal WHILE visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432202/unable-to-change-options-for-twitter-bootstrap-modal-after-visible/18476669#18476669)

It has two answers, but neither one answers my question. (Note, also, that both answers are from the same user) Is there any way I can get more people to see other than starting a bounty? Although I've edited it, I have not seen additional activity, nor have I seen it on the front page.

Comment: You can link the question on meta. That will give it more views :P

Comment: you can edit something in your question and it will be displayed at the top of SO questions queue for a bit. Also I have already asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181662/questions-with-1-answer-not-accepted-get-ignored-by-people)

Comment: @mehow I made an edit, and it still says "Last Active: 2 days ago," so that hasn't bumped it.

Comment: @Mat Editing isn't bumping my question to the front page. The last active time is still "2 days ago."

Comment: @Mooseman: you edited it two days ago. (And yes, editing does bump.)

Comment: @Mooseman any reason you are opposed to a bounty?  Or are you just checking for other alternatives

Comment: @Mooseman editing does bump a post, but given the volume of questions on Stack Overflow, it doesn't stay on the front page more than an hour and usually mot much more than 20-30 minutes (depending on the time of day).

Answer (score 5):

You could try sharing it on a social network site, or by e-mail if you know someone who could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your question with some more details; that would bump it up the list. If the edit is sufficient, it should attract more attention and hopefully an answer.