# Why are moderators not taking any action on my flag?

Tags: support, flags

Yesterday I have asked one question and that is good as conceptually as my opinion, but I didn't know another user did not agree with my question.

So at one stage I thought to delete my own question, but unfortunately one user has posted his answer so I can't delete after that.

So I flagged to a moderator to delete my question, but I don't know why still no action is taken by moderators.

How much time will it take by moderators?

Please support me.

Comment: Why do you want to delete that question? There are lots of questions with [declined feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-declined)...

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? Even though it wasn't a very popular suggestion, it's still useful to keep it around. Then, if anyone asks for the same thing again, we can close it as a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @hims056 because now don't want more down votes. :(

Comment: @chintankhetiya - We have already told you that [downvotes are different here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182316/why-cant-we-edit-other-users-comments#comment-555265). Please take it lightly...

Comment: Now that it's disappeared from the front page, it's unlikely to gather a significant number of additional downvotes. I wouldn't worry about it. After all, a single upvote will offset 5 of those downvotes.

Comment: @hammar as i told you that is good as my opinion but some other are not agree with mu suggestion, never expect down votes. :( now it might be possible that will get down vote. that is only reason.

Comment: Also deleting questions/downvoted question lead you to [a question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824).

Comment: @hims056 this is my first question that i want to delete. so in future i can't ask any question more ?

Comment: @hims056: People keep saying that, but is there actually any evidence  that this is the case? As far as I can see it only says that downvotes on deleted questions count, not that they count any more than other downvotes.

Comment: @hammar so what should i do ? i have already flag to moderators.

Comment: Wait and see. That's all. If they don't delete it, they don't. Move on.

Comment: okay. thanks for lovely suggestion. have a good day ahead. :)

Comment: @hammar - Please read *Are deleted posts taken into account too?* in that question.

Comment: what is your opinion about my question,?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you note, there is an upvoted answer to your question. We don't delete questions with answers unless there is a valid reason to do so, even by request. Getting heavily downvoted on meta is not a valid reason.

I just checked, and your flag had already been declined some time ago with the exact same reasoning.

Comment: then what should be my valid reason? my question is not useful in future. so is it okay ?

Comment: It is useful in the future. Users with similar ideas can see it has been proposed before and declined.

Comment: okay as other use suggest me to don't delete.it could be helpful to other if they will try to search or ask same thing.

Comment: The "valid reason" needs to come from you. If you can't think of a valid reason to have your question removed, it would be wise not to flag for it. Even if your question isn't useful, the answers are often worth keeping around. That's why you're not allowed to delete your own question when there are answers.

Comment: okay move on.thanks buddy :)