# Remove the [removing] and [removal] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I see the [remove](/questions/tagged/remove) tag [has been taken care of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134690/remove-tag-should-be-removed). However, its equally worthless cohorts [removing](/questions/tagged/removing) and [removal](/questions/tagged/removal) remain. How about banishing those as well?

Comment: I agree with the removal of ... [removal], and I also think that removing [removing] is a good idea.

Comment: After we have removed the removing and removal tags i propose we remove this post on removing the removing tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done.

[image: Burninated with meta colors]

Comment: Needs moar colorz!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Did you forget this is _meta_, [where color is not tolerated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta)?

Comment: @Shog9: What happens when someone requests a tag removal?  I hope that the tag(s) is(are) put into a blacklist lest they should be resurrected.  I have seen people respond to tag elimination requests with, "There are only N questions with that tag, just remove them yourself."  This is unsatisfactory because it doesn't prevent the next ignorant bastage from bringing the tag back from the dead.

Comment: If it gets *repeatedly* recreated, we can blacklist it @raven. That said, most of these tend to be tags that were created accidentally a long, long time ago before we raised [the reputation threshold for tag creation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on Stack Overflow and folks would routinely create new tags by just typing their titles into the tag field. Both removing and removal date back to at least early 2009.

Comment: @Shog9: That's the help page I was looking for.  Cool.  However, I submit that that privilege should require even more reputation points.  I was looking at [the new tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=9&tab=new) the other day and I saw some crap like "txt".  But, looking at them just now I don't see anything too heinous.  Hmm...  I'll just assume you guys have it under control <ha, haha, hahahaha...>.