# Why do the mobile sites not have the same colour scheme as the full site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, mobile-web

I think the different colour schemes for the sites are a good idea, it gives a 'personality' to the site.

Why get rid of the them on the mobile site? The blue colour scheme for this main meta full site *looks good*, it was [changed to that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/42985#42985) from a distasteful gray scheme, so why don't we have it on the mobile site?

My feature request is to have the same colour schemes for both the full site and the mobile site, for all non beta sites.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's way too much work, and the designers are **already** [running behind by several months](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/code-review-se-is-graduating) to create designs for sites that are graduating.

And the mobile theme is meant to be compact and functional, a goal that it hits. Adapting each graduated site's colour scheme to the mobile skin could actually *detract* from the usability. There simply isn't enough scope there to put in design elements and vary the colours for each and every site.