# Can the colors for the editing page in stackapps be changed?

Tags: feature-request, design, stackapps

The colors for the edit page in stackapps is:

1. Eye Hurting
2. Makes text unreadable

Could it be changed to something nicer?

[image]

Comment: Can read it just fine, without any eye pain at all

Comment: To the close voter, there is no meta.stackapps.com. This site serves as Stack Apps's meta.

Comment: Clearly that page was designed by a [Longhorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Longhorns).

Answer (score 3):

I just saw the hi-res (by clicking on the image) version of your screenshot and I can read the text *clearly*. I'm using MacBook Pro Retina with a 22.1-inch Dell Monitor.

As for the changing of the background color goes, SE's UI/UX team has made a custom theme for StackApps.com as a whole and not just for the "edit" page. I can clearly see the same theme has been carried over as I navigate through various sections/tabs of the site. If *changed*, then it should be made throughout the entire site and not just for "edit" page.

Also, one can always change the CSS code if your browser supports them. For example, Firefox with GreaseMonkey. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104/can-you-bring-the-color-back-to-meta/417#417) for more details. You can restyle the web pages with popular **[Stylish](https://userstyles.org/)** browser add-on (extension). I use *Stylish* on few of my favorite websites.

Here is a screenshot of the StackApps edit page after using the ["Stylish" Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) (and here is [FireFox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stylish/) link.):

> [image]

All I did was, install the *Stylish* extension (took less than 20 secs), copied the relevant CSS code by doing inspect element, created a new style with obtained CSS code by changing (as shown below) the background-color hexa code and pointed it to https://stackapps.com/ domain so that it gets applied to every page of the site. You can also do this for a *specific* page.

```
.newuser {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
code {
    font-family: Menlo,Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;
    background-color: #EC7C44;
}
```

Please change the background-color #000000 and #EC7C44 to whatever is comfortable for your eyes. It's that easy.

Comment: _Goes to write userscript_

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy The answer also suggests ["Stylish"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy please see my updated answer. It's a temporary workaround. I use this on few of my sites